# Correct Sample Size N in a Relative A/B Test with Binomial Variates

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, sample-size, standard-error, ab-test

I randomly assign users to two distinct groups and track their return rate to the website (the return rate on each day for each group is simply $\frac{Number Of ReturningUsers}{TotalUsersOnDayZero}$). I have two groups, $X$ and $Y$, and I'm calculating the $SEM$ of the following relation:

$$ Z = \frac{X-Y}{Y} $$

Since the experiment runs over 7 days in a row, I'm comparing the two groups day by day.

To calculate the $ SEM $ I need first to get the **Expected Value** and **Variance** of $Z$ using [Taylor Expansions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables)

1. The Expected Value is calculated with

$$ E[\frac{X-Y}{Y}] = \frac{E[X-Y]}{E[Y]} - \frac{Cov[X-Y,Y]}{E[Y]^2} + \frac{E[X-Y]}{E[Y]^3}Var[Y] $$

2. The Variance is calculated with
   $$ Var[\frac{X-Y}{Y}] = \frac{Var[X-Y]}{E[Y]^2} - \frac{2E[X-Y]}{E[Y]^3}Cov[X-Y,Y] + \frac{E[X-Y]^2}{E[Y]^4}Var[Y] $$

Then I calculate the $SEM$ with

$$ {SEM_i} = \frac{\sigma_i}{\sqrt{N_i}} $$

where $i$ represents the day

### **What is the right sample size ${N_i}$ to use in that case?**

1. is it the number of users that returned on that day ($Nx_i+Ny_i$)?
2. is it the $max(Nx_i, Ny_i)$?
3. is it the number of days I run the experiment (7)?